# Field 'XXX.AppMain.p1' is Never Assigned to, And Will Always Have Its Default Value Null

Tags: c#, list, null, field, assign

I don't understand why I'm getting this error message, when I've clearly assigned a value to p1, as you can see in the following code:

```
public class AppMain
{
    private static GraphicsContext graphics;
    private static bool running;
    private static Sprite bckgnd1, bckgnd2;
    private static Sprite openScreen, instructScreen, gameOverScreen;
    private static Vector3 pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5;
    private static Player p1, p2;
    private static Fruit apple, orange, banana;
    private static Stopwatch clock;
    private static long startTime, stopTime, deltaT;
    private static Random rand;
    enum GameState {
        opening,
        instructions,
        play,
        gameOver};
    private static GameState currentState;
    private static List<Player> pList;


    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Initialize ();

        while (running == true) {
            startTime = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            SystemEvents.CheckEvents ();
            Update ();
            Render ();
            stopTime = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            deltaT = stopTime - startTime;
        }
    }

    public static void Initialize ()
    {
        running = true;

        pList = new List<Player>();

        graphics = new GraphicsContext ();

        Texture2D pTex1 = new Texture2D("/Application/Assets/macmuffin.png", false);
        Texture2D pTex2 = new Texture2D("/Application/Assets/macmuffin1.png", false);

        pos1 = new Vector3(200, 600, 0);
        pos2 = new Vector3(400, 600, 0);

        Player p1 = new Player(pTex1, pos1, 1, graphics, "Player 1");
        Player p2 = new Player(pTex2, pos2, 2, graphics, "Player 2");
        pList.Add (p1);
        pList.Add (p2);
    }
```

Also, bonus points if you can tell me why when I try to render the players, the error message "Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Cain_Game3.AppMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0" shows up. Thanks.

Comment: You have a `p1` variable and a `p1` field. The field is not assigned to.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a new, locally scoped p1, not assigning to the p1 member declaration near the top.

You probably want to change this:

```
  Player p1 = new Player(pTex1, pos1, 1, graphics, "Player 1");
```

to this:

```
  p1 = new Player(pTex1, pos1, 1, graphics, "Player 1");
```